# The norm of a bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space is the norm of the vector?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

If $L$ is a bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space $H$, then we know that
$$Lx=(x,y),\quad \forall x\in H,$$
for some $y\in H$. Is it true that $\|L\|=\|y\|$?

We have by Cauchy-Schwarz that
$$|Lx|=|(x,y)|\leq\|x\|\|y\|,$$
so $\|L\|\leq\|y\|$, but what about the other inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Unless $y=0$, we have
$$\|L\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(x,y)|\geq|(y/\|y\|,y)|=\|y\|.$$
If $y=0$, then $\|L\|=0=\|y\|$.